# Gromov-Witten invariant $\langle p, p, \ell\rangle_{0, 1}$ counting degree $1$, genus $0$ curves in $\mathbb{CP}^2$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, gromov-witten-theory, mirror-symmetry

Let $p \in H^4(\mathbb{CP}^2)$ and $\ell \in H^2(\mathbb{CP}^2)$ be the cohomology classes Poincaré dual to a point and a line respectively.

**Question.** What is the Gromov-Witten invariant $\langle p, p, \ell\rangle_{0, 1}$ counting degree $1$, genus $0$ curves in $\mathbb{CP}^2$?

Comment: This is equivalent to asking for the number of straight lines passing through two general points in the plane, i.e. 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dan says, you can use the divisor equation:
$$\langle e_{\alpha_1}, \ldots, e_{\alpha_n}, \ell  \rangle_{g,d} = d\  \langle e_{\alpha_1}, \ldots, e_{\alpha_n} \rangle_{g,d} $$
where the $e_{\alpha_i}$ are any cohomology classes of $\mathbb{CP}^2$, to reduce your invariant $\langle p,p,\ell \rangle_{0,1}$ to $\langle p,p\rangle_{0,1}$, the number of lines through two points.